# Animated short with a monkey boy in it

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Ok so, I think this may have been a series of shorts that they played during commercials on Cartoon Network. It had this one character who was a young kid with Monkey features, he had messy dark hair (either dark brown or black) and I think a tail. It was animated with a style that was kind of blocky but I can't recall if it was CG or not. I saw it at some point between 2008-2014

Comment: Can you remember what was particularly science fictional or fantastical about the show? As of now there isn't anything that is clearly on-topic for the site. Be aware, anthropomorphic animals are not considered fantastical unless there are humans or something of the like present making it "abnormal".

Comment: I think they may have been fighting some sort of robot in a sort of underground setting. And I also think they were using magic, like when you can hold it to make your punches or kicks stronger.

Comment: [Mojo Jojo](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=%22Mojo+Jojo%22)?